# PHP word wrap when unwanted

Tags: php

For some reason, any 2 or 3 character strings are word wrapping the last character down a line.

Output of my code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eJziCQ5QSNyXjxSKUgBum7ngEWGpAgy-

Code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Bo Testing Form
 * Version: 0.0.1
 * Description: Testing PDF Template for a form.
 * Author: Bo Curtis
 * Group: RSU#3
 * License: GPLv2
 * Required PDF Version: 4.0-beta
 */
/* Prevent direct access to the template (always good to include this) */
if ( ! class_exists( 'GFForms' ) ) {
    return;
}
/**
 * Load our template-specific settings
 */
$show_meta_data = ( ! empty( $settings['world_show_meta_data']) ) ? $settings['world_show_meta_data'] : 'No';
/**
 * Include your PHP variables in this section
 */
$name = $form_data['field'][9];
$deadlinedate = $form_data['field'][12];
$event = $form_data['field'][13];
$dates = $form_data['field'][14];
$para1 = $form_data['field'][15];
$para2 = $form_data['field'][16];
$para3 = $form_data['field'][17];
$fee = $form_data['field'][18];
$meals = $form_data['field'][23];
$lodging = $form_data['field'][26];
$lodgingpernight = $form_data['field'][24];
$lodgingnights = $form_data['field'][25];
$lodgingoption = $form_data['field'][27];
$mileage = $form_data['field'][28];
$mileagecost = $form_data['field'][31];
$misccosts = $form_data['field'][32];
$totalmisc = $form_data['field'][33];
$totalcost = $form_data['feld'][34];
$adminsignature = $form_data['field'][3];
$admindate = $form_data['field'][4];
$fundaccts = $form_data['field'][6];
$fundsapproved = $form_data['field'][58];
$suptsignature = $form_data['field'][1];
$suptdate = $form_data['field'][2];
$actualmeals = $form_data['field'][47];
$actuallodging = $form_data['field'][48];
$actualmileage = $form_data['field'][49];
$actualmileagecost = $form_data['field'][50];
$actualother = $form_data['field'][51];
$actualtotal = $form_data['field'][52];
$employeesig = $form_data['field'][53];
$lodgingcostpernight = (string)$lodgingpernight;
?>

<!-- Any PDF CSS styles can be placed in the style tag below -->
<style>
    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #055811;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    }
        p {
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                color: 000000;
                white-space: nowrap;
        }
</style>

<div style="position: fixed; top: 118; left: 100"><?php echo $name; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 140; left: 125"><?php echo $event; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 185; left: 20"><?php echo $para1; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 210; left: 350"><?php echo $para2; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 233; left: 320"><?php echo $para3; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 120; left: 600"><?php echo $deadlinedate; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 145; left: 600"><?php echo $dates; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 270; left: 615"><?php echo $fee; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 290; left: 615"><?php echo $meals; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 325; left: 615"><?php echo $lodging; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 325; left: 135"><?php echo $lodgingcostpernight; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 325; left: 305"><?php echo $lodgingnights; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 407; left: 230"><?php echo $mileage; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 407; left: 615"><?php echo $mileagecost; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 450; left: 110"><?php echo $misccosts; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 450; left: 615"><?php echo $totalmisc; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 465; left: 600"><?php echo $totalcost; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 510; left: 350"><?php echo $adminsignature; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 510; left: 615"><?php echo $admindate; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 632; left: 125"><?php echo $fundaccts; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 632; left: 630"><?php echo $fundsapproved; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 655; left: 155"><?php echo $suptsignature; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 655; left: 600"><?php echo $suptdate; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 770; left: 340"><?php echo $actualmeals; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 795; left: 340"><?php echo $actuallodging; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 820; left: 250"><?php echo $actualmileage; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 820; left: 340"><?php echo $actualmileagecost; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 847; left: 340"><?php echo $actualother; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 847; left: 615"><?php echo $actualtotal; ?></div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 830; left: 520"><?php echo $employeesig; ?></div>


<?php if ( 'Yes' == $show_meta_data ): ?>
    <p style="font-size: 0.8em;">
        <strong>User IP:</strong> <?php echo $form_data['misc']['ip']; ?><br>
        <strong>Submission Timestamp:</strong> <?php echo $form_data['misc']['date_time']; ?><br>
        <strong>User Agent:</strong> <?php echo $form_data['misc']['user_agent']; ?><br>
        <strong>Source URL:</strong> <?php echo $form_data['misc']['source_url']; ?>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I am far from a PHP expert, so it is probably something simple, but any help is welcomed! Thank you!

Comment: Please post your code a text and not a link

Comment: Can you reduce your code to the relevant parts? Where does the wrap occur, and why do you think that the problem is PHP related?

Comment: I am not sure what the relevant parts are honestly, and I am not 100% certain if it is PHP related but I didn't know what else it would be related to. Like I said, I am not an expert I am just starting to get to know PHP enough to write this code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by manually setting the divs to a width greater than what they needed to be. I cant remember the username of the guy who had an answer here that appears to have been removed, but thank you kind sir for your assistance.